# Stop audio after 60 seconds without loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

so I have a audio of 10 seconds but I want to stop the option replay after 60 seconds inside the page and I don't want the audio to loop. But the audio keeps looping to 5.

```
var iterations = 1;

            document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

                if (iterations < 5) {

                    this.currentTime = 0;
                    this.play();
                    iterations ++;

                    document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

                }
            }, false);
```

Comment: What's that `}, false);` at the end?

Comment: I saw that code from a link and I think the false if like, if is superior to 5 it stops

Comment: But I want to change the 5 to 60sec but I don't know how. I have the iterations because I need to count the number of replays

Comment: set a timeout and bind it to a variable, if timeout reached 60 sec then kill that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `setTimeout()` for stopping the audio after a certain amount of seconds. Here is an example that starts playing an audio file and stops it after 6 seconds.

```js
document.getElementById('audioSample').play();
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('audioSample').pause();
}, 6 * 1000); // Stops the audio player after 6 seconds
```

```html
<audio controls id="audioSample">
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

```js
let countdown = 6;

document.getElementById("audioSample").play();

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  countdown -= 1;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = countdown;
  if (countdown <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("audioSample").pause();
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<audio controls id="audioSample">
      <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

<div>Time left:</div>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: It's like that, but imagine a quizz game where you have 60s to responde, I need the audio to play everytime and count the times but once 60s are reached I the audio doesnt play anymore.

Edit: Forget I can put a audio to replay 6 times max if the audio is 10s, but how can I stop the loop?

Comment: @DanoninhaMartins: I have just edited the answer and have added a more elaborate example with a countdown. Does this help?